# Width of fingers (computer vision)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to compute the width of fingers in an image.
what i did , is i binarized the image, which gave me the hand in white and background in black.

i fixed the y axis at : y=156
the image binarized called thresh

why don't i get the result of the print (width)

the idea, is to loop over the x axis , in my example i choosed range (x,xD)
then i look for indices where there is transition from black to white and from white to black.

```
for i in range(x,xD):
    if thresh[i-1][156]==0 and thresh[i][156]==255:
        b2w = i
    if thresh[i-1][156]==255 and thresh[i][156]==0:
        w2b = i
        width = w2b - b2w        
        print(width)
```

Comment: You will need to provide more context and information for your example.  While prone to a lot of possible errors, if I just make a list of length 100 of all zeros, but make the indices 40:60 255, and run your loop on the list, it prints the expected value of 20.  You will need to provide some example data that highlights where things are going wrong

Comment: @VinceW. i don't get any error.
thresh is just a binarized image (stackoverflow does'nt let me put image here), the image is for a hand. (hand is white and background is black)
let's take x = 51 and xD = 412
i drew a line of equation y=156 and i want to get the intersection with fingers, 
so i loop over the thresh (binarized image) with two conditions if, to get the transition from white to black and from black to white, and the difference between indices is the width

Comment: I understand what you're doing.  What I'm saying is that for a very simple case like I described, there is nothing wrong with your loop.  If you are having a problem it probably means that your image data at y=156 looks different for some reason than the example I mentioned, but without an example data set, I can only guess at what might be wrong.  You could create a stringified version of the values at y=156 and add them to the question, which might help

Comment: That's what's making me crazy, i see the line intersects the image in four points and the line's equation is y=156.
this is thresh[200]= [ 
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255 255
 255 255 255 255 255   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0 255 255 255 255 255
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  
   0]
and thresh[200][156] will give me as result= 255

Comment: can you provide me the list for y=156?  You can do this with `line = [x[156] for x in thresh]`

Comment: @VinceW.
I can't it's too long to put in a comment of stackoverlow, but here is the link to a doc:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Z6oe72esBHUJ8s8x7GgkE2am0w78OITj2_GnVCPgldM/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your loop will fail unless there are clear starting and ending points in your picture.  If your finger runs all the way to the edge, you never meet the condition where `thresh[i] == 255 and thresh[i-1] == 0` evaluates to True.  In the dataset you shared via Google Docs, this is exactly what happens.

There are many ways to tackle this.  One is to use the list index method with exception handling.  You could also do a loop with a check if you are at the end.  Packages like numpy and pandas will have other tools available.  Here is a snippet that shows using the list index method and catching the case where you hit the end of the line without actually having a boundary:

```py
# lst = [x[156] for x in thresh]  # to actually pull the slice from your data set
# your data pasted from Google Docs
lst = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255]

# so you can change it to what you want
start = 0
end = len(lst)
# end = 10  # will trigger the first except clause printing finger is not in the slice

try:
    first_255 = lst.index(255, start, end)
    try:
        last_255 = lst.index(0, first_255, end)
    except ValueError:
        last_255 = end
    print(f"width: {last_255 - first_255}")
    print(lst[first_255:last_255])
except ValueError:
    print('finger is not in the slice')
    first_255 = None
    last_255 = None
```

prints:

```
>>> width: 408
>>> [255, 255, 255, ... 255, 255]
```

Comment: W, i think i had to clarify my final goal,
well, in order to compute the width of fingers, i drew contours, & binarized the image, also i drew a bounding box that passes through extrem points of hand, the zone i'm interested in, is the one on top (where fingers are), so what i'll do, is drew some parallel lines which i have there equations, y=156 & there are 4 more, y=200 ...etc) 
https://ibb.co/vsQSpgr
loop frm left to right using x and y range & check for transition from black to white pixel on binary image & note positions; get difference between 2 transitions and thats the width

Comment: okay... so did this solve your problem, or are you still having a problem?

Comment: well, it didn't work!
thresh is a numpy array, its length is 577, 2 dimensions and size=249841

Comment: do you mean that thresh is an array with 577 rows and 249,841 columns?  Or is it 577 rows and 433 columns.  If the array is structured as you have indicated, this should not be a problem.  If it is a problem, it means there is another detail missing here.  Can you post the full data set somewhere and the full script that imports the data set and gives an erroneous result

Comment: W, thank you, i found out how to apply your idea to my problem,
the problem is, it just computes the first finger, i'm trying to get the width of more fingers:
for example: 
lista = [0,0,0,255,255,255,0,0,255,255,255,255,255,255,0,0,0,0,0,0,255,255,255]
for x, v in itertools.groupby(lista):
    ok = list(v)
    if ok[0] == 255:
        print(ok)
but how can i assign a variable to each sublists of the result?

Comment: best just to save the grouper objects as a list of lists: `segments = [list(v) for x, v in groupby(lista)]` which you need to do anyway since you don't know in advance how many there will be, or whether `0` or `255` will come first

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what i did, i used the library itertools, 0 is always the first it's assigned for the black background, and i should always have 4 sublists of 255, because i had to detect 4 fingers.
Thanks again @Vince W.